# How to redirect an USB 3.0 device to VM in virt-manager?

Tags: usb, kvm-virtualization, qemu, virt-manager

usb 3.0 devices never worked on virt-manager for me. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on both host and guest, and only 2.0 redirection works. When I do 3.0, it simply does not appear on the guest on lsusb neither on disks (for a flash drive for example)

I'm using the "redirect usb device" option, and the virt-manager is 2.2.1

Comment: What does the "Controller USB 0" tab on the left panel, USB 2 or 3? Have you tried changing it to USB 3? See [this page](https://www.spice-space.org/usbredir.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, as pointed by @user68186, it's just a matter of choosing USB3 on Controller USB 0

[image]